# Counting The Repetitive Item in Specific Column

Tags: python, count, counter, repeat

Hye. I am a new Python user. I need to do some scripting that will extract the data from specific .txt file. The data in the file are:

```
Milo    12345678901234  DN127   POTATO_123_456  
Milo    12345678901234  DN127   POTATO_123_456
Lamb    12345678901307  DN127   TOMATO_123_456
Lamb    12345678901618  DN127   TOMATO_123_456
Lamb    12345678901953  DN127   TOMATO_123_456
Milo    12345678902213  DN127   CHILI_789_0126  
Milo    12345678902822  DN127   BANANA_134-123
```

What the script will do is, it will only display the line that has word "Milo" and count the repetitive item in the 4th column (column 3). I manage to do display the line with word "Milo" but didn't have idea on how to count repetitive word in column 8. Here what I did so far:

```
with open ("food.txt") as food:
                for line in food:
                    if line.find("\tMilo")!=-1:
                        print(line)
```

Comment: Can you show expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pandas:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('food.txt', sep = " ", header = None)
df.columns = ['Product', 'ID', 'Another ID', 'Some Code']

df = df[df['Product'].isin(['Milo'])]
df['Count of Repetitive Some Code'] = df.groupby('Some Code')['Some Code'].transform('count')
```

**Legend:**

`Product` is your column with `Milo, etc`

`ID` is your column with `12345678901234, etc`

`Another ID` is your column with `DN127, etc`

`Some Code` is your column with `POTATO_123_456, etc` ==> the one you want to count.

Comment: For Some Code, is it will count any word that repeated or on able to count for the code that I assign? As the column that has POTATO_123_456 has thousands of different item besides those four.

Comment: Doesn't matter how many unique values there are in 'some code' column. It will count how many instance, a unique value in that column is repeated. Just basic countif in excel.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helps me a lot!

Comment: Just wonder, the code is run but there is no display when i run the code. Should i add up print () and which variable should i print?

Comment: You can print the column itself so that you'll see the values themseleves. Also a quick note if you want to see count vs unique in that column you may use the `value_counts` method by. `df['column to count'].value_counts()`

Comment: And don't forget to accept answer and upvote, glad to have helped :))

Comment: Done. I am also new with stack. Sorry for the late upvote and accepting

Comment: Hye Joe. Just came out with one last problem. I want to sort the repetitive of "Some Code". I used df.sort (['Some Code']) , ascending = False. It turns out the same result and randomly display withou sorting. Hope you can help if came across this comment :)